# How to use strings.xml in a list without static issue?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, static

I'm working on an app on Android Studio, who will be in 2 differents languages. I did two differents strings for each language. I had to put the strings in a list and call a Random for show at the user a different notification every day.

Here's my code :

**The strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="notifications">

    <item>No1</item>
    <item>No2</item>
    <item>No3</item>
    <item>No4</item>
    <item>No5</item>

</string-array>
```

**The class Choose.java**

```
public class Choose extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] conseils=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.notifications);

public String getPhraseHasard() {

    Random random = new Random();
    int hasard = random.nextInt(conseils.length);

    return conseils[hasard];

} }
```

**The class Notification.java**

```
public class Notification extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 .....

    NotificationCompat.Builder myNotifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            myNotifBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_mind);
            myNotifBuilder.setContentTitle("A tip");
            myNotifBuilder.setContentText(Choose.getPhraseHasard());
            myNotifBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(Choose.getPhraseHasard()));
            myNotifBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);


    notifManager.notify(goOn, myNotifBuilder.build());

} }
```

My problem :
getPhraseHasard() is a non-static method so I can't use it in Notification.
When I put static in Choose, I can't because getResources() is a non-static method too.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: you need an instance of Choose class...

Comment: Maybe it will be useful to read something about the basics of Java programming language. BTW [Static vs. non-static](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20static%20vs%20non-static&rct=j)

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

Just Create a object:

```
 Choose mchoose = new Choose();
```

then call like this :

```
mchoose.getPhraseHasard()
```

Answer (score 0):

[getResources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) is a method of [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class.

You can delete `getPhraseHasard` declaration and use getResources from `Context` putting your logic in `onReceive` method. You could also receive a `Context` in input for `getPhraseHasard` method and use it in a **static** way.